# Как закрыть три формы при нажатии на кнопку в третей форме?

Tags: c#

Есть три формы, мне нужно их все сразу закрыть при нажатии на кнопку в форме 3. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Comment: Это зависит от того как вы их открывали.

Comment: Смотрите, например, свойство [Application.OpenForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например:

```
class Form1 : Form {
}

class Form2 : Form {
}

class Form3 : Form {
    private Form form1;
    private Form form2;

    public Form3(Form form1, Form form2) {
        this.form1 = form1;
        this.form2 = form2;
    }

    // При нажатии на кнопку вызываем этот метод
    private void CloseThree() {
        this.form1.Close();
        this.form2.close();
        this.Close();
    }
}

class Application {
    static void Main() {
        var f1 = new Form1();
        var f2 = new Form2();
        var f3 = new Form3(f1, f2);

        // тут показываем формы и т.д.
    }
}
```